# Sort Postal Codes Alphabetically & Numerically PHP

Tags: php, sorting

Playing around with a custom built CMS and I have an issue where I have several Postal Codes saved to the database relating to a specific store.

I am loading them within an Object array as such

```
Array ( 
  [0] => PostalCodes Object ( 
    [ID] => 0fea73e60ef4e5809e1ec4900a1f6075
    [StoreID] => 7f0563d8e451d2342ca4b6a3b5402665
    [PostalCode] => L2E
  )
  [1] => PostalCodes Object (
    [ID] => 11e82b7f0e69dd3982352cf6b983ca9f
    [StoreID] => 7f0563d8e451d2342ca4b6a3b5402665
    [PostalCode] => L0R1S0
  )
)
```

My question is what would be the most efficient way to sort them mixed Alphabetically & Numerically before outputting them in a for each loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is called[`usort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), and you can simply use [`strcmp()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) on the postal codes.

```
function myCompare($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->PostalCode, $b->PostalCode)
}

usort($myarray, 'myCompare');
```

Also, in your future postings be sure to post your data with more easily readable formatting. A lot of people will not bother to take the time to read or reformat what you originally posted.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and edit! Point taken on formatting! I really appreciate the wealth of resources provided here at StackOverflow.